# Equation environment, equation number parenthesis, are both righthanded

Tags: equations

I am using the template in [this link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/technion-iit-thesis-template/rzqpztzgppwz). As can be seen from the PDF, the parentheses on the equation number (chapter 3 equation 1 for example) are both right-handed. How can I fix this? In general, I could not find where they even load the `amsmath` package.

Comment: I cannot even compile it on Overleaf without it timing out. Might not be the best template to use. I tried running it locally against TeXLive 2021, but that fails on some packages. The files for the template seems to make some assumptions and redefinitions of macros without checking if they exists

Comment: I have compiled it a number of times on overleaf. It takes a bit of time and sometimes it clocks out, but a second compile completes the job. It has so much benefit for me, I cannot dismiss this template.

Comment: I would, given that it can only be compiled by old latex installations. It really ought to be updated by who ever is responsible for it. For such a short example, compilation should not take that long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to successfully compile the `thesis.tex` file included in the distribution after some changes which I will list later.

Regarding your question, I found that all the parentheses in the numbers of the equations were fine.

Just in case I have included samples of the sample paper for the `amsmath` package. Filename: `\testmath.tex` to check other delimiters. No problems found.

**Changes**

(1) Font. I did not have  the font `David CLM`, but  I found the `DavidCLM` font already in my system directory. (Perhaps from David Libre from a former project. See [What Hebrew fonts can I substitute for David in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472768/what-hebrew-fonts-can-i-substitute-for-david-in-lualatex-or-xelatex))

So I commented  line 133 of `iitthesis.cls` and defined a  `\newfontfamily` in the preamble pointing to the right place.

(2) In the file  `my-thesis-specific.tex` I changed `\renewcommand\lips@dolipsum{`  for `\newcommand\lips@dolipsum{` to eliminate the  `! LaTeX Error: Command \lips@dolipsum undefined`.

**Note** The full kit obtained from the official site https://github.com/eyalroz/technion-iit-thesis/ instead of Overleaf does not have this problem. (fixed on Mar 7, 2020)

(3) I removed an error message (coming from the paragraph before the last in `\abstractHebrew{`) commenting `\include{front/abstract}`. Other Hebrew text were typeset OK. See  last figure

**Eq. 3.1**

[image: aa]

[image: a]

[image: c]

This is the new `thesis.tex`

```
\documentclass[PhD,noabbrevs]{misc/iitthesis}

\include{misc/thesis-fields}
\include{front/personal-acks}
 %\include{front/abstract}
\include{front/abbrevs}

\usepackage{misc/iitthesis-extra}

\include{misc/my-general}
\include{misc/my-thesis-specific}

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{pubinfo}{Acknowledgement page references}
\def\iitthesisextramultibibdefs{}
        
\usepackage{amsmath} % added to test eq. samples <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    %\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM} % changed: line 133 of iitthesis.cls <<<<<<<<<<<
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    Path =C:/Windows/Fonts/,%
    Script=Hebrew,%
    Language = Hebrew ,
    Extension =.ttf,%
    UprightFont =*-Medium,%
    BoldFont =*-Bold,%
    ItalicFont =*-MediumItalic,%
    BoldItalicFont =*-BoldItalic%
    ]{DavidCLM} 

\begin{document}
    

\makefrontmatter
\include{main/intro} 
\include{main/prelims}
\include{main/mainchap1}

\include{main/short_testmath} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\include{main/conclusion}
\appendix
\include{main/appendix1}
\makebackmatter 
\end{document}
```

This is the file `short_testmath.tex`

```
%% file short_testmath.tex

\newcommand{\wt}{\widetilde}
\newcommand{\wh}{\widehat}

\section{Introduction}

This paper contains examples of various features from \AmS-\LaTeX{}.

Sample Paper for the \textbf{amsmath} Package.

 File name: \textbf{testmath.tex}

\section{Enumeration of Hamiltonian paths in a graph}

Let $\mathbf{A}=(a_{ij})$ be the adjacency matrix of graph $G$. The
corresponding Kirchhoff matrix $\mathbf{K}=(k_{ij})$ is obtained from
$\mathbf{A}$ by replacing in $-\mathbf{A}$ each diagonal entry by the
degree of its corresponding vertex; i.e., the $i$th diagonal entry is
identified with the degree of the $i$th vertex. It is well known that
\begin{equation}
\det\mathbf{K}(i|i)=\text{ the number of spanning trees of $G$},
\quad i=1,\dots,n
\end{equation}


Let $C_{i(j)}$ be the set of graphs obtained from $G$ by attaching edge
$(v_iv_j)$ to each spanning tree of $G$. Denote by $C_i=\bigcup_j
C_{i(j)}$. It is obvious that the collection of Hamiltonian cycles is a
subset of $C_i$. Note that the cardinality of $C_i$ is $k_{ii}\det
\mathbf{K}(i|i)$. Let $\wh X=\{\hat x_1,\dots,\hat x_n\}$.


\begin{equation}\label{H-cycles}
\biggl(\prod^n_{\,j=1}\hat x_j\biggr)H_c=\frac{1}{2}\hat k_{ij}\det
\wh{\mathbf{K}}(i|i),\qquad i=1,\dots,n.
\end{equation}

Then, it follows that
%\begin{lem}\label{lem-det}
\begin{equation}\label{detprod}
\prod_{i\in\mathbf{n}}
\biggl(\sum_{\,j\in\mathbf{n}}b_{ij}\hat y_j\biggr)
=\biggl(\prod_{\,i\in\mathbf{n}}\hat y_i\biggr)\det\mathbf{B}.
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}\label{detB}
\det\mathbf{B}=
\sum^n_{l =0}\sum_{I_l \subseteq n}
\prod_{i\in I_l}(b_{ii}-\lambda_i)
\det\mathbf{B}^{(\lambda)}(I_l |I_l ),
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
\mathbf{K}(t,t_1,\dots,t_n)
=\begin{pmatrix} D_1t&-a_{12}t_2&\dots&-a_{1n}t_n\\
-a_{21}t_1&D_2t&\dots&-a_{2n}t_n\\
\hdotsfor[2]{4}\\
-a_{n1}t_1&-a_{n2}t_2&\dots&D_nt\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{j:mark}
\begin{split}
H_c=&
\frac{n_1!\,n_2!\,n_3!}
{n_1+n_2+n_3}\sum_i\left[\binom{n_1}{i}
\binom{n_2}{n_3-n_1+i}\binom{n_3}{n_3-n_2+i}\right.\\
&+\left.\binom{n_1-1}{i}
\binom{n_2-1}{n_3-n_1+i}
\binom{n_3-1}{n_3-n_2+i}\right].\end{split}
\end{equation}
```